# How to store multiple values in array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add multiple values to array each time when i pass some values to this page(cart.php).

but now i am able to get only one value from array.i also tried

```
echo $_SESSION['cart'][1];
echo $_SESSION['cart'][2];
```

but i am able to get only one value which is newly added and i am getting notice

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1
Notice: Undefined offset: 2
```

cart.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && isset($_GET['product_id'])){
            if($_GET['action'] == "add"){
                $product_id = $_GET['product_id'];
                $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
                array_push($_SESSION['cart'],$product_id);     
            }
        }
?>
```

this is how i am passing the values in query string

```
 http://localhost/mycart.php?action=add&product_id=4
```

Comment: I think there's no need for `product_id parameter`... coz you're using `session` to get the products.

Comment: You are passing only one product_id and this product id should be at the position zero of the array, so you have to echo this way echo $_SESSION['cart'][0]; to see the results or just do var_dump/print_r the array

Comment: @Tommy yeah but its storing everything in [0]; .

Comment: the problem here is that you are resetting the array every time, you must delete this line of code $_SESSION['cart'] = array();, this way you will add element after element to the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always overwrite the array and so, you get only one value in it.
Try this:

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && isset($_GET['product_id'])){
            if($_GET['action'] == "add"){
                $product_id = filter_var($_GET['product_id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
                $_SESSION['cart'][] =$product_id;
            }
        }
```

Comment: array_push has the same effect

Comment: Look at all the code, basicly, i kiled one line, so it works with array_push or $myArray[], but like the php.net docu said, better use $myArray[].
http://php.net/array_push